# How to see time that one IP login on Gmail?

Tags: gmail, google-account, security

The "last account activity" link on Gmail shows just last 10 logins. How can find more, and exact time (including hour, minute) for one IP address?

Answer (score 2):

The "[My Activity](https://myactivity.google.com/myactivity)" page will show *everything* you've done with your Google Account, including all of your Gmail accesses. Unfortunately, it doesn't show IP addresses (although it will show the device used to access).

If you're concerned that someone may be accessing your account from elsewhere, go to the "[Recently used devices](https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity)" page under *My Account*. There you can see all of the devices (with OS and location) that have accessed your account in the last 28 days and, if necessary, you can remove access.

Unfortunately, Gmail will only show the last 10 accesses. There isn't a way to get more.